# I have trouble configure android studio header file

Tags: android, android-studio

I have the driver install, but i do not see what the problem is.

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you added dependency in gradle file

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your gradle file
make sure you added this dependencies

```
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0'
```